# How to extract Data from a COLLADA .dae file with Python?

Tags: python, xml, collada

im pretty new to working with XML and COLLADA.
I know how to inspect a XML File. But when using the commands that work on a XML File, i get strange results with a COLLADA File.

The COLLADA File is a Layout of an appartment and i just need the Values of the Walls and the resulting squaremeters.

Here is the actual layout:
[image]

1. Problem: How do i find the right tags, that store these values?
2. Problem: How do i extract them?

When trying to just display all the child nodes:

```
for elm in root.findall("./"):
    print(elm.tag)
```

I get this result

```
{http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema}asset
{http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema}library_images
{http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema}library_effects
{http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema}library_materials
{http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema}library_geometries
{http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema}library_visual_scenes
{http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema}scene
```

Here is a part of the COLLADA File (original is way too long):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
  <asset>
    <contributor>
      <authoring_tool>three.js Collada Exporter</authoring_tool>
    </contributor>
    <created>2022-06-27T10:03:13.052Z</created>
    <modified>2022-06-27T10:03:13.053Z</modified>
    <unit name="threeUnits" meter="0.049999999999999996" />
    <up_axis>Y_UP</up_axis>
  </asset>
  <library_images>
    <image id="image-1" name="image-1">
      <init_from>image-1.png</init_from>
    </image>
    <image id="image-2" name="image-2">
      <init_from>image-2.png</init_from>
    </image>
    <image id="image-3" name="image-3">
      <init_from>image-3.png</init_from>
    </image>
    <image id="image-4" name="image-4">
      <init_from>image-4.png</init_from>
    </image>
  </library_images>
  <library_effects>
    <effect id="Mat1-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>1 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat2-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>1 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat3-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>1 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat4-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>1 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat5-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>1 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat6-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>1 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat7-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>1 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat8-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>1 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat9-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat10-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat11-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat12-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat13-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat14-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat15-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat16-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat17-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
        <extra>
          <technique profile="THREEJS">
            <double_sided sid="double_sided" type="int">1</double_sided>
          </technique>
        </extra>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat18-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
        <extra>
          <technique profile="THREEJS">
            <double_sided sid="double_sided" type="int">1</double_sided>
          </technique>
        </extra>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat19-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
        <extra>
          <technique profile="THREEJS">
            <double_sided sid="double_sided" type="int">1</double_sided>
          </technique>
        </extra>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat20-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
        <extra>
          <technique profile="THREEJS">
            <double_sided sid="double_sided" type="int">1</double_sided>
          </technique>
        </extra>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat21-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
        <extra>
          <technique profile="THREEJS">
            <double_sided sid="double_sided" type="int">1</double_sided>
          </technique>
        </extra>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat22-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
        <extra>
          <technique profile="THREEJS">
            <double_sided sid="double_sided" type="int">1</double_sided>
          </technique>
        </extra>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat23-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
        <extra>
          <technique profile="THREEJS">
            <double_sided sid="double_sided" type="int">1</double_sided>
          </technique>
        </extra>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat24-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
        <extra>
          <technique profile="THREEJS">
            <double_sided sid="double_sided" type="int">1</double_sided>
          </technique>
        </extra>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat25-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat26-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat27-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat28-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat29-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat30-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat31-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat32-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat33-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat34-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <newparam sid="diffuse-surface">
          <surface type="2D">
            <init_from>image-1</init_from>
          </surface>
        </newparam>
        <newparam sid="diffuse-sampler">
          <sampler2D>
            <source>diffuse-surface</source>
          </sampler2D>
        </newparam>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>1 1 1 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat35-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <newparam sid="diffuse-surface">
          <surface type="2D">
            <init_from>image-2</init_from>
          </surface>
        </newparam>
        <newparam sid="diffuse-sampler">
          <sampler2D>
            <source>diffuse-surface</source>
          </sampler2D>
        </newparam>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>1 1 1 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat36-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <newparam sid="diffuse-surface">
          <surface type="2D">
            <init_from>image-3</init_from>
          </surface>
        </newparam>
        <newparam sid="diffuse-sampler">
          <sampler2D>
            <source>diffuse-surface</source>
          </sampler2D>
        </newparam>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>1 1 1 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
            <transparent>
              <texture texture="diffuse-sampler">
              </texture>
            </transparent>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat37-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <newparam sid="diffuse-surface">
          <surface type="2D">
            <init_from>image-4</init_from>
          </surface>
        </newparam>
        <newparam sid="diffuse-sampler">
          <sampler2D>
            <source>diffuse-surface</source>
          </sampler2D>
        </newparam>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>1 1 1 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
            <transparent>
              <texture texture="diffuse-sampler">
              </texture>
            </transparent>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat38-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat39-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0.9058823529411765 0.9058823529411765 0.9058823529411765 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
        <extra>
          <technique profile="THREEJS">
            <double_sided sid="double_sided" type="int">1</double_sided>
          </technique>
        </extra>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat40-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0.9058823529411765 0.9058823529411765 0.9058823529411765 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
        <extra>
          <technique profile="THREEJS">
            <double_sided sid="double_sided" type="int">1</double_sided>
          </technique>
        </extra>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    <effect id="Mat41-effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="common">
          <constant>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <reflective>
              <color>0 1 0 1</color>
            </reflective>
            <reflectivity>
              <float>1</float>
            </reflectivity>
          </constant>
        </technique>
        <extra>
          <technique profile="THREEJS">
            <double_sided sid="double_sided" type="int">1</double_sided>
          </technique>
        </extra>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
  </library_effects>
  <library_materials>
    <material id="Mat1">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat1-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat2">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat2-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat3">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat3-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat4">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat4-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat5">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat5-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat6">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat6-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat7">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat7-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat8">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat8-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat9">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat9-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat10">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat10-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat11">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat11-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat12">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat12-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat13">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat13-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat14">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat14-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat15">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat15-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat16">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat16-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat17">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat17-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat18">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat18-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat19">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat19-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat20">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat20-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat21">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat21-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat22">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat22-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat23">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat23-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat24">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat24-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat25">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat25-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat26">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat26-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat27">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat27-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat28">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat28-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat29">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat29-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat30">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat30-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat31">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat31-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat32">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat32-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat33">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat33-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat34">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat34-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat35">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat35-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat36">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat36-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat37">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat37-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat38">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat38-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat39">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat39-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat40">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat40-effect" />
    </material>
    <material id="Mat41">
      <instance_effect url="#Mat41-effect" />
    </material>
  </library_materials>
  <library_geometries>
    <geometry id="Mesh1">
      <mesh>
        <source id="Mesh1-position">
          <float_array id="Mesh1-position-array" count="12">0.4374000132083893 0 0 0.19619999825954437 0 0 0.19619999825954437 0.24660000205039978 0 0.4374000132083893 0.24660000205039978 0</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor source="#Mesh1-position-array" count="4" stride="3">
              <param name="X" type="float" />
              <param name="Y" type="float" />
              <param name="Z" type="float" />
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <vertices id="Mesh1-vertices">
          <input semantic="POSITION" source="#Mesh1-position" />
        </vertices>
        <source id="Mesh1-normal">
          <float_array id="Mesh1-normal-array" count="12">0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Take a look at [pycollada](https://pycollada.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Yeah i am already exploring the documentation.